# How to share class methods between multiple data models in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have multiple Active Record data models in Ruby on Rails that need to share class methods. I could easily declare the methods in all the classes but that is against the DRY principle.

I've looked at declaring a module and using 'include' to mixin the code but that seems to only work with instance methods, not class methods.

What is the preferred way to do this in Ruby/Rails? (I tried to create a base ActiveRecord class and inherit from that, but ActiveRecord freaked out).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ClassMethods idiom is a common way for a module to supply both class and instance methods: http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/

ActiveRecord shouldn't freak out if you create an abstract base class, as long as you call `self.abstract_class = true` in that class: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Bingo! self.abstract_class = true was what I was missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `extend` instead of `include` with a module. That'll mix in class methods instead of instance methods.

Or you absolutely can inherit your base model from `ActiveRecord::Base` and inherit all your normal models from this base. ActiveRecord shouldn't freak out.

Comment: I couldn't get inheritance to work. E.g. class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base, and sub-class class Bar < Foo. When you call Bar.find(x) Active Record throws a "Could not find table 'foos'" error. Ideas?

Comment: I think this is the answer you needed. This is nothing related with ActiveRecord but with Ruby its shelf. Try to create Ruby Modules for the common methods and `extend` from them.

Comment: Leonard, you'd need to declare your table name in the class